# How to consume WCF remote service in .net 6 with service reference

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, soap-client, svcutil.exe, corewcf

Okay, my head is dizzy because I have spent past week looking for a solution or a decent explanation.

Here is my not so hard goal: I just need to take remotely hosted SOAP service (Created long time ago in a galaxy far, far away), connect it to my class library, which will then be used by ASP.NET WebApi.

Did not seem very hard at first, Except, I can not get any response from this service, no matter how I try.

In usual cases it returns null, but when I comment a **DebuggerStepThroughAttribute** on service implementation and place a breakpoint inside of any method, an exception is fired: ***System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException***. Channel and InnerChannel throw this exception and I can not figure out how to get rid of it. I get the feeling that this entire client does not send the needed requests to the remote service.
I have a Postman request built and functional, which sends regular POST request with xml body and receives a response, so remote service is not faulted.

I followed every instruction which I could find, even [samples](https://github.com/CoreWCF/samples) on Github for CoreWCF, I was still not able to figure this out. My entire code is generated by svcutil, dependency injection part and options part was written by me. I will attach all the files:

**connectedServices.json file, generated by VS2022:**

```
{
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "https://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, RevenueService"
    ],
    "targetFramework": "net6.0",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

**Also generated Channel interface (I have no idea what this is or how to use it):**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
public interface WayBillsSoapChannel : RevenueService.WayBillsSoap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}
```

**ServiceContract with one of the methods:**

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="RevenueService.WayBillsSoap")]
    public interface WayBillsSoap
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/get_error_codes", ReplyAction="*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RevenueService.get_error_codesResponse> get_error_codesAsync(RevenueService.get_error_codesRequest request);
    }
```

**Implementation of service contract:**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
public partial class WayBillsSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<RevenueService.WayBillsSoap>, RevenueService.WayBillsSoap
{
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);
    
    public WayBillsSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
            base(WayBillsSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), WayBillsSoapClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public WayBillsSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(WayBillsSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public WayBillsSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(WayBillsSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public WayBillsSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
            
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
    }
    
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
    }
    
    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.WayBillsSoap))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            return result;
        }
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.WayBillsSoap12))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            textBindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressingVersion.None);
            result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
            httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
            return result;
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
    
    private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.WayBillsSoap))
        {
            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx");
        }
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.WayBillsSoap12))
        {
            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx");
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
    
    public enum EndpointConfiguration
    {
        
        WayBillsSoap,
        
        WayBillsSoap12,
    }
}
```

**Options class:**

```
public class RevenueServiceOptions
{
    public string? ServiceUrl { get; set; }

    public string? ServiceUser { get; init; }

    public string? ServicePassword { get; init; }

    internal void Validate()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceUrl))
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(RevenueServiceOptions)}.{nameof(ServiceUrl)} should not be empty");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceUser))
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(RevenueServiceOptions)}.{nameof(ServiceUser)} should not be empty");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServicePassword))
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(RevenueServiceOptions)}.{nameof(ServicePassword)} should not be empty");
    }
}
```

**And DependencyInjection logic:**

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static void AddExternalServices(this IServiceCollection services, RevenueServiceOptions revenueServiceOptions)
    {
        services.AddRevenueServiceOptions(revenueServiceOptions);

        services.AddServices(revenueServiceOptions);

        services.ConfigureAutoMapper();
    }

    private static void AddRevenueServiceOptions(this IServiceCollection services, RevenueServiceOptions revenueServiceOptions)
    {
        if (revenueServiceOptions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(revenueServiceOptions));

        revenueServiceOptions.Validate();

        services.AddSingleton(revenueServiceOptions);
    }

    private static void AddServices(this IServiceCollection services, RevenueServiceOptions revenueServiceOptions)
    {
        services.AddScoped<WayBillsSoap>(_ =>
            new WayBillsSoapClient(WayBillsSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.WayBillsSoap, revenueServiceOptions.ServiceUrl));
    }

    private static void ConfigureAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapper());
        });

        var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    }
}
```

*serviceUrl, serviceUser and servicePassword is taken from appsettings.json file*

Could you please tell me, am I doing something wrong? does this client need additional configuration to send POST requests? Or could you, may be, give me an advise about a good resource which I was not able to find and which will actually help?

Thank you.

P.S. While here, could you also tell me how or where to use **ConfigureEndpoint** partial method?

Comment: You are using HTTPS which uses TLS for encryption.  Did old code use HTTP or HTTPS? TLS is sent before the HTTP request is sent.  So we need to determine if TLS completed or failed.  If you have a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler check what version of TLS is being used and check if request is sent.  You can also check the event logs in the server to see if any errors occurred.  HTTP is encrypted and you will not see the message in the sniffer, but if you change the https to http you will be able to capture the request and compare to the Postman.